# Poor quality output after merging multiple image into one using Montage of ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, montage

I tried to merge multiple jpg images files into one jpg using `magick montage -border 0 -tile 4x3 *.jpg outputfile.jpg` but the image is very very poor quality.
[image]

How do I enhance the high-quality image or same quality image after merging all files into one? 
[image: Original Sample]

Comment: Please post your original images separately, so tha the can use them to demonstrate. In what way is the result poor quality. If the input images are low resolution, then the output will also be. You also loose quality by starting with JPG images and saving to JPG. JPG is a lossy image format and will need to be decompressed when read and recompressed for output. So each of those steps loses some quality. You can add -quality 100 to your output and see if that helps. But the file size will be larger. Alternately, save to compress PNG or TIFF to avoid the lossy JPG output compression.

Comment: It's that the original jpeg resolution deteriorates after making a collage. yes, tiff preserves the quality but I need the quality to be preserved even after merging the files in jpeg.

Comment: All you can do is set -quality 100 before the output. If that does not suit your requirements, then you are out of luck, since JPG is lossy.